# CKeditor get text area content instead of html with angular 5

Tags: angular, ckeditor

In my application i used ckeditor for description section.

```
<ck-editor [(ngModel)]='ticket.description' [ngModelOptions]="{standalone: true}" skin="moono-lisa" language="en" [fullPage]="true"></ck-editor>

This should save as html content to data base while save so it can be display in table with htlm tag. But i need only content what i gave in text area.
```

[image]
    I have highlighted what content i need to display.

Answer (score 1):

Im not expert in CKEditor but `[fullPage]="true"` insert `<html><body></body></html>` at your `ticket.description`.

Try `[fullPage]="false"`

[More about CKEditor config](https://docs.ckeditor.com/ckeditor4/latest/api/CKEDITOR_config.html#cfg-fullPage)

[More about CKEditor full page](https://docs.ckeditor.com/ckeditor4/latest/guide/dev_fullpage.html)

Answer (score 1):

We need to use innerHTML while display in table

For Example:
  I used mat table like

```
<ng-container matColumnDef="description">
        <mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef mat-sort-header> Description </mat-header-cell>
        <mat-cell *matCellDef="let row" [style.color]="green" [innerHTML]="row.description">  </mat-cell>
      </ng-container>
```